# How can I detect 'busy' signal when dialing in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an Android app. In that I am unable to detect the busy signal when I am dialing some number, so my call ends abruptly.

Is there anyway I can get to know that call is busy, other than using call duration to determine (as this will not work with different carrier)?

Comment: I think this would be your answer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html